# Is it legal for two individuals in California, United States to place a bet between themselves?

Tags: united-states, california, gambling

Alice wants to make a bet with Bob (e.g., betting 100 USD that tomorrow there will be no snow falling in a given location, or that some new phone to be announced tomorrow will cost less than 1k USD). Bob agrees to the bet. Is that legal, and is the bet legally enforceable (i.e., Bob must pay Alice if he loses)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No

California has no [laws](https://content.next.westlaw.com/9-635-9371?__lrTS=20210131124256061&transitionType=Default&contextData=(sc.Default)&firstPage=true) on social gambling so it is treated identically to commercial gambling. Since betting on outcomes other than sports betting is illegal in California, such a bet would be illegal.

While it’s unlikely to be prosecuted, as a contract it would be void its illegality and thus unenforceable.